# Trying to add a coloured hover to a slick carousel

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to add a colored hover over an image on a slick carousel on Wordpress and can't figure out how to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, so we can help you!

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ We can't figure out without any code as well. So please add a code snippet of what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

So the general gist is to make an element appear in front of the image which has the colour you want as the hover effect. So you may need to alter the plugins html, but as you are using wordpress i would see in the plugin documentation if there is a way to overwrite the relevant file in your child theme as you should never directly alter a parent file in this situation.

here is a rough example you can follow:

```
<div class="overlay_wrapper">
   <div class="layer_1">
     <p>image goes here</p>
   </div>
   <div class="layer_2">

   </div>
 </div>

 .overlay_wrapper {
   width: 500px;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
   background-color: #000;
   margin: 0 auto;
   color: #fff;
}

 .overlay_wrapper .layer_2 {
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin: auto;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
   transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay_wrapper:hover .layer_2 {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/oPXrgJ